# Javascript/JQuery GetDay()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following code:

http://jsfiddle.net/SPWWx/

I'm completely new to javascript, this is my first time using it. The values of the HTML selects MUST be 01,02 etc, that's why I had to use a big long if else statement. The values have to be submitted to an application on a server, which is extremely fussy about what way it takes in values.

Why won't it set the day as 15 (today) in the select box?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a few issues, you're not including jQuery on the left, the element has a **name** not an **ID** or `CID`, so it needs to be `id="CID"` or your selector needs to be `select[name='CID']`.  Last, you need to pass a string to `.val()` to get the result you want, otherwise it's trying to set it to `"4"`, which doesn't equal `"04"`.

You can shorten all your code down to this though:

```
var day = new Date().getDate().toString();
$("#CID").val(day.length == 1 ? "0" + day : day);​
```

[You can test it here](http://jsfiddle.net/nz2Uu/1/), also as [Jamiec](https://stackoverflow.com/users/219661/jamiec) points out, you want `.getDate()` to get the date *of the month* as opposed to `.getDay()` which is *of the week*.

Comment: This is right, and should be the accepted answer. Just to add one thing; use `CurrentDate.getDate()` to get the day number (15 for today).

Comment: Nice and comprehensive. I'd just been finding the first two problems, when you'd already sorted it.

Comment: @Marcus you should mark this as the answer if it has helped you.

Comment: One more quick one, for month and year would it be the same idea?

Comment: @Marcus - Similar yes, but `.getMonth() +1` for month, and `.getFullYear()` for year, here's a full list: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp

Comment: @Marcus - Almost :) `.getMonth()` is 0-11, so you need a +1 like this: http://jsfiddle.net/nz2Uu/3/

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, saved me a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

because the element's name is CID, not it's id! $('#CID') selects the element with the id CID.